# C# using SQlite in project by on user computer it's using a different version?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am using C# and using sqlite and shipping these files with my program

SQLite.Interop.dll
System.Data.SQLite.dll

right beside myprogram.exe

My Program is installed like this.

C:\Program Files\MyAPPlication\myprogram.exe

I am getting error reports and crashed because the Users Computer is using SQLite from this location

```
[System.Data.SQLite] System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand : System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteStatement GetStatement(int ) in 'c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteCommand.cs' at Line 314, Column 35
```

I don't understand why it's not using the version I packed with the program.

In all of my code I am using it like this..

```
           using (SQLiteConnection sqLconnect = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Class_GlobalVars.StrDbPath + ";Version=3;PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;"))
            {
               //code
            }
```

Can anyone tell me why c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite is being referenced?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path specified in a stack trace is not the path where the dll is found, it's the path where the dll was compiled from.  It won't match the path on the deployed location (except in development).

Ask a new question with your full exception for help with that.  It's not likely related to the location or version of SQLite.